# iCloud breach and what to do following it

Tags: icloud, security, find-my-iphone

I have reason to believe that my iCloud account was recently breached and whoever did it is trying to lock my devices. I am aware that this is done through Find my IPhone and that they have set it to lost mode. However, when I go to Find my IPhone and I view the details of my mac, it simply says locked 6 minutes ago without an option to un-lost mode it. Is there any way to fix this / am I doing something wrong or do I have to go to an apple store and prove I own the device and such?

Thanks all,

Jimmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would only have to go into an Apple store and prove ownership if your device is "bricked" after iOS/macOS is erased (meaning you cannot login to it due to forgotten password and/or Apple ID email address). When iCloud.com says the device is "locked" it does not mean "bricked," it simply means the *screen* is locked, like with your pin.

It sounds like all you need to do is **enable 2-Factor authentication** in your Apple ID/iCloud account, plus **change your password**. This will prevent whomever "breached" the account from logging in again. See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915

Comment: The problem is that someone managed to get access already and has locked my mac with Find my iPhone. The screen looks like this: [img of screen](https://sophosnews.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/500-locked-mac1.png?w=500&h=263); this means they have already locked my mac and I am not sure how to unlock it, would this be similar to a "bricked" device? Thanks!

Comment: Afraid so, yes. You need to produce a receipt and go into the Apple Store to get it unlocked (if you don't know the code). Good luck.

Comment: BTW, if this MacBook is stolen (not saying you did, but just in general) it is worthless now, FYI.

Comment: @Jimmy, can you award me the answer here, please? I believe I properly answered your question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to the store today so I'll see how it goes, thanks for the help